# intermittent big query table Unavailable error

Tags: google-bigquery

When I run a query on a table as the table owner. I get the error (Error 400,Error: Something went wrong with the table you queried. Contact the table owner for assistance.). The same query might work or It might not work intermittently.

The jobId when the query worked is 
            planar-fulcrum-837:bquijob_66c2e13e_15846fef94c
              The jobId when the query failed is 
            planar-fulcrum-837:bquijob_cba7f3d_15846ff1370

Both query are the same. Only one table is affected while other table under the same project is unaffected.

The table in question has 37 columns as is 324 GB is size. Data are continuously streamed into the table. The query ran look something like this

```
         SELECT 
  substr(datehourminute,1,4) [year],
  substr(datehourminute,5,2) [month],
  substr(datehourminute,7,2) [day],
  substr(datehourminute,9,2) [hour],
  sidentifierid, pidentifierid
  ,count(*) as leads
  FROM iqleads.leads 
  WHERE 
  integer(substr(datehourminute,1,10)) between 2016051400 AND  2016051523       AND sidentifierid IN (10)
  GROUP BY 
   year,month,day,hour,sidentifierid, pidentifierid
  order by 
   year,month,day,hour,sidentifierid, pidentifierid
```

Many thanks in advance for reading through this question.

Comment: https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/bigquery/18022

Comment: Thanks @MikhailBerlyant for sharing the link. I will follow the link for update. For now I will keep the question open until the api have been resolved to make sure the error is indeed related to the api downtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error appear to be contributed to big query streaming api downtime.

https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/bigquery/18022

All the errors are resolved after the api was fixed by google.